# Finding rows in table using input from a CSV file - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

Using a SQL tool like SQL Developer / Toad for Oracle

Is it possible to write a SQL query that will do the following

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN1 IN CSV_FILE
```

The CSV file is just one column of data with no delimiters.

How can I achieve this?

**Constraints**

I cannot create a temp table to insert CSV file (no create permissions)

The data I am using of this column is the only index in that table so I cannot use other columns to query or else it will be really slow.

Thanks

Comment: What does this possibly have to do with jQuery? Please make sure you tag questions appropriately.

Comment: Having the same issue. Using a file as input for query condition. Did you find a solution to this? I don't have 'permissions' either, but my permission is more of a no no thing. I'm just not allowed to create new tables on the TFP database as that could get crazy. Were you able to use utl_file or anything else to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating external table is the best way. If you dont have permission then the other way is to move the file to the path of any oracle directory(Oracle object - Directory). And with help of utl_file read the file, loop through it and do your operation inside a PL/SQL block which is too tedious.

See the eaxmples for using utl_file - http://psoug.org/reference/utl_file.html

But its better if you try and get create access.

Answer (score 1):

1. Toad for Oracle data import (uses sqlldr internally)

   - Create a temp table and load the data using this utility and select the values
2. External tables

   - Create external table, load the data through the same and select the values.

Comment: Hi, I do not have create permissions so cannot create a temp table.

Comment: For sure every user can create a table in their own schema in Oracle

Comment: Files should made available for oracle to be read in the OS. Which is definitely going to ask for a temp table or external table to hold the data in Oracle way and not as a flat file

Comment: Im sorry but I am still struggling on this concept, I have looked at external tables documentation but I am not sure how I query with this.

Comment: What about if I created a table on my own database, can I query between two databases on SQL Developer?

Comment: What is your OS and mention their versions.

Comment: querying two different DB is possible but unnecessary for a simple operation like this.

Comment: Win 7 32bit, with oracleclient 10g, I prefer to use SQL developer

Answer (score 0):

Using *SQL developer* you can create a table in your schema and load this table with data from a *csv* file.

Notes:

1. You will need to create a void column per each column to import from *excel*
2. *Excel* export *csv* with `";"` delimiter
3. If *SQL developer(4.1.5)* doesn't preview the fields in separated columns try moving forward/backwards with Next/back buttons

and a very graphical guide in the following page:
http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/